# Angular 1.x Testing with Jasmine: Compiling a template not working to verify data output in template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-templatecache

I am trying to unit test an html template that has variables in paragraph, anchor tags, and `{{header.title || translate}}` however no matter what posts I have tried it does not seem to work. I get the retrieved HTML template and when it is compiled it is still the same. In the template I still see `{{user}}` for example. It seems none of them are actually being compiled.

**Current Template Output:**

```
<h1>{{header.title | translate}}</h1>
<h2>{{homeCtrl.name}}</h2>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<h1>Cake Blogger</h1>
<h2>Alexandria</h2>
```

**Test Suite:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('home.tpl.html', function() {
    var scope, controller, createController, template, element, rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('Templates'));
    beforeEach(module('mainApp'));

    /**
      @name: home.tpl.html
      @description: Inject and set test related objects
      @param {Service} rootScope - Used to get the language
      @param {Compiler} $templateCache - Holding the compiled template
      @param {Injector} $compile - Compiles an HTML string or DOM
    */
    beforeEach(inject(
      function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, $templateCache, $compile) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        createController = function() {
          return _$controller_('homeCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
         });
      };

      controller = createController();

      rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      template = $templateCache.get('home.tpl.html');
      element = $compile(template)(rootScope);

      // var ctrl = element.controller('homeCtrl');
      rootScope.$digest();
      console.log("home page", element);
  }));

  /**
    @name: Describe Block - home.tpl.html
    @description: Test cases related to home.tpl.html
  */
  describe('home.tpl.html tests', function() {
    fit('should have "Alexandria"', function() {
      expect(element.html()).toContain("Alexandria");
    });
  });
});
})();
```

**Karma File:**

```
files: ['list of files'],

port: 8080,

browsers: [
  'PhantomJS'
],

plugins: [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
],

preprocessors: {
  'app/**/*.tpl.html': 'html2js'
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  'moduleName': 'Templates',
  'stripPrefix': 'app/'
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
    "grunt-karma": "*",
    "grunt-modernizr": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
    "karma-fixture": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-json-fixtures-preprocessor": "0.0.6",
    "karma-json-preprocessor": "^0.3.3",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

According to posts I have read such as this plunker from a post [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBvAkNgYTaEMEHqW3yMZ?p=preview), this should be working correctly. I am thinking perhaps the controller is not binding to the scope so that when `$digest` runs the template cannot find the controller maybe.

**Helpful Information:**

- Where it says `rootscope.$digest()` I also tried it as `scope.$digest()`, I also tried using `$apply()`.
- I am using `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor`
- I am using `TemplateCache`
- I am using `$compile`

**Links viewed:**

- [how to access controller in directive [jasmine]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914201/how-to-access-controller-in-directive-jasmine)
- [$compile not compiling templates in Karma/Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238220/compile-not-compiling-templates-in-karma-jasmine)
- [Don't work $compile in Jasmine Karma Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827101/dont-work-compile-in-jasmine-karma-angular)
- [Unit Testing AngularJS directive with templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl)

The template returns but the angular in the template is never compiled. Always seeing `{{homeCtrl.name}}` instead of `Alexandria`.

**Update 1.1**

I am thinking perhaps since the translate `{{header.title | translate}}` is not working that maybe `angular-translate` (module: `pascalprecht.translate`) is not actually working correctly and is then causing the controller to also fail binding. Will continue investigation.

Answer (score 1):

After injecting `angular-translate` the `| translate` filter just works and yields expected translated value after $compile. See this plunker as an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/j8rbnMI067YntllwTcGi?p=preview

One possible reason that leads to your issue is timing - suppose you have big translate array / json and it takes a while to load, but Jasmine testing already starts and finishes before they are fully loaded and ready. Then Jasmine will see un-translated string during tests.

---

Updated 2017-06-30

After a few experiments, I can confirm that any async json loader, whether it's `.useStaticFilesLoader` or `$.getJSON()`, will not be executed before jasmine. See http://plnkr.co/edit/nreUd52iqOVvwLPMNtJA?p=preview as an example, the static loader works fine for page view but fails unit test.

One possible way to go is to ditch `.useStaticFilesLoader` completely. Instead, we can use `grunt-replace` to inject the translations during the build process. Example grunt task:

```
// replace string with json
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: /\"JSONEN\"/,
          replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("app/resources/en.json") %>'
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['app/scripts/app.js'], dest: 'public/'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I had jasmine timeout in the test suite as well karma timeout in the karma.conf set to 10 seconds. Did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: So I added 500 lines to plunker and it still runs perfectly fine. I am thinking the error is project specific perhaps.

Comment: I don't see a bug really, you just have to know about that static files loader is asynchronous and $translate.instant is synchronous. So mixing these two is not a good idea with this setup.

Comment: english json file is: locale-en_US.json. Where are getting this 'public folder'?

Comment: tried switching to this: replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("app/resources/locale-en_US.json") %>'